# HTML CSS/JS Path Error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two directory in a server: Project A and Project B. In my local development server, both projects work normally. In actual live server, everything is normal in Project A, but this happens to Project B.

My HTML:

```
<link href="mydir/lib/css/css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="mydir/lib/css/css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="mydir/lib/css/css3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

But instead it echoed:

```
<link href="mydir/lib,_css,_css1.css+lib,_css,_css2.css,lib,_css,_css3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

or

```
<link href="mydir/A.lib,,_css,,_css1.css+lib,,_css,,_css2.css+lib,,_css,,_css3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This happened not only for including CSS, but for JS too. My page CSS display seems normal, but my JS sometimes is not working (undefined functions or variables, but they are already in the included JS files). I don't know if the JS error happened because of this.

Directory name doesn't matter, I tried to change them, sometimes it works, sometimes not. Whether the files actually exist or not doesn't matter too, and again in this case, sometimes it works, sometimes not. Tried not to include or run any JS too, not working. Absolute/relative path doesn't matter too.

This is the first time this happens to me, I couldn't pinpoint why. Does anyone know why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you somehow register your CSS and JS? Because if you statically write your HTML, it's not possible for such errors.

Comment: @Justinas Tried to loop the files name using PHP at first. Then I delete them, and typed all of them normally in HTML, still happens. I thought my PHP code was wrong too, but it's the exactly same one in the working Project A.